# iPhone simulator screenshot not capturing device bezel

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, simctl

I'm trying to capture a simulator screenshot using Xcode 12. Right now, even though the "Show Device Bezels" option is enabled (and it shows the bezels on the screen), when I take the screenshot, the bezel isn't part of the resulting screenshot. I've tried through the camera button on the simulator, through the "Save Screen" menu item, through "xcrun simctl screenshot" command-line as well, but it doesn't work correctly.

Weirdly, it was working fine just yesterday, but I was playing with setting the "defaults write com.apple.screencapture disable-shadow -bool TRUE" from the command-line (to prevent the shadow in video capture of the window) ... I'm not sure if that's related to this issue, and I flipped it back to FALSE, but that doesn't seem to help either.

I've also tried restarting the simulator, restarting the Mac, switching "Show Bezel" on/off, using Xcode11, erasing contents of simulator.... but it's still not working. Very frustrating.

This is what it looks like:
[image: screenshot-no-bezel]

Any tips of what I can try?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The bezel is not saved as part of the screenshots from Simulator.app / simctl.  The only option you have is whether or not the framebuffer mask is applied.

If you want the bezel, you'll need to use the macOS screenshot support.  Hit shift-cmd-4, then hit space to toogle from "draw the rectangle" mode to "select the window" mode.  Then click on the window to take a screenshot.

Comment: The problem there is that it then includes the title bar above the device bezel, which I don't want. It was working before, and saving the device bezel as well (when using the camera button on top of the simulator) ... but not sure what caused it to stop working.